# Why my Tomcat 7 stop working after deploy

Tags: java, grails, deployment, tomcat7

I have a grails app that runs on dev environment and I crated the war without problems.
In the server, I stop the service using "**sudo service tomcat7 stop**" command and put the war file into the server folder "**/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps**" and start the server again with the command "**sudo service tomcat7 start**".
For checking the state of the server I run "**sudo service tomcat7 status**" and get the "*Tomcat servlet engine is running with pid 19169*" response, and check if the application deploys correctly on the folder "**/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps**" and I see the project's folder there.
Right now, if I check the catalina.out file, I can't see any deploy error having this:

> May 27, 2020 9:04:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO:
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"] May 27, 2020 9:04:31 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
>   processed in 1280 ms May 27, 2020 9:04:31 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina May 27, 2020 9:04:31 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 May 27, 2020 9:04:33 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO:
>   Deploying configuration descriptor
>   /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/docs.xml May 27, 2020 9:04:33 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO:
>   Deploying configuration descriptor
>   /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml May 27, 2020 9:04:33
>   PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO:
>   Deploying configuration descriptor
>   /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml May 27, 2020 9:04:33 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO:
>   Deploying configuration descriptor
>   /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/examples.xml May 27, 2020 9:04:33 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR INFO: Deploying web
>   application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/fleetcontroller.war
>   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (net.bull.javamelody). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system
>   properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

But if I wait a while, the tomcat service is stoped.
When I check the server status with "**sudo service tomcat7 status**" I get this msg

*Tomcat servlet engine is not running, but pid file exists.*

And the catalina.out show me:

> WARN  intercept.RequestmapFilterInvocationDefinition  - Exception
>   initializing; this is ok if it's at startup and due to GORM not being
>   initialized yet since the first web request will re-initialize. Error
>   message is: {0} 2020-05-27 21:14:13,192 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN 
>   module.ModuleDeclarationsFactory  - resources artefact
>   KickstartResources does not define any modules | Using LESS files to
>   generating CSS files!

Please, if someone can help with that, because I don't know how to find the problem.

Really thanks for your time.

Comment: If your tomcat dies, this most likely is something ugly (e.g. the OOM hitting). I'd dig deeper on the logs to find out was happening (e.g. also check /var/log/messages and dmesg, and if you are on systemd what the journal has to offer).

Comment: Hi @cfrick thanks for answer. I will check that and write here what happened. The most stranger thing is that the env. is a clone of production, where all is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It was a **virtual machine size problem**.
I checked some server parameters and see that they was lower than production. infrastructure office changed the virtual server size and it starts to work!

Thanks you for your time!